# How can I change this Listview to open another Activity Istead of toast massage

Tags: javascript, android-activity, android-listview

I need t change this Listview to open different activity by position instead of making a toast for example when I click on the first row it opens First Activities and for second row it opens Second Activity

```js
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private ListView lv;

 private String title[] = { "Cup Cake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo",
   "Ginger Bread", "Honey Comb", "Icecream Sandwich", "Jelly Bean" };

 private String desc[] = { "version: 1.5", "version: 1.6",
   "version: 2.0 & 2.1", "version: 2.2", "version: 2.3",
   "version: 3.0", "version: 4.0", "version: 4.1" };

 private int thumb[] = { R.drawable.cupcake, R.drawable.donut,
   R.drawable.eclair, R.drawable.froyo, R.drawable.gingerbread,
   R.drawable.honeycomb, R.drawable.icecreamsandwich,
   R.drawable.jellybean, };

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  // initialize the variables:
  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

  lv.setAdapter(new VersionAdapter(this));

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
     long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int pos = arg2;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflator = getLayoutInflater();

    View layout = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
      (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_iv);
    TextView tv = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_tv);

    iv.setBackgroundResource(thumb[pos]);
    tv.setText(title[pos]);

    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
   }
  });

 }

 class VersionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

  public VersionAdapter(MainActivity activity) {
   // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return title.length;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return position;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return position;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   View listItem = convertView;
   int pos = position;
   if (listItem == null) {
    listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
   }

   // Initialize the views in the layout
   ImageView iv = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
   TextView tvTitle = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.title);
   TextView tvDesc = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.desc);

   // set the views in the layout
   iv.setBackgroundResource(thumb[pos]);
   tvTitle.setText(title[pos]);
   tvDesc.setText(desc[pos]);

   return listItem;
  }

 }
```

For example something like this but I dont Know how to combine

```js
String classes[] = { "First", "Second", "Third" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menuone.this,
   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

if (position == 0) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, First.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
else if (position == 1) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
 else if (position == 2) {
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Third.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 } 
 }

 }

 }
```